# yolov5 does not train the model

Tags: python, pytorch, yolov5

I trained a dataset by [yolov5](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/wiki/Train-Custom-Data). The model is existed but it does not work. It does not predict excatly.

Here the code I used:

`python train.py --img 640 --batch 8 --epochs 3 --data ../datasets/coco128/coco128.yaml --workers 0 --image-weights '' --name test`

outputs of the code:

[image]

[image]

[image]

When we look at the test folder for prediction:

Labels

[image: labels]

Predictions

[image: Predictions]

As you see, predictions are nothing. Also there are best.pt and last.pt files. Their size are 14.475 mb. But google colab works with same code.

Also when I try to predict images with default yolov5s.pt, it works, predictions are right.

matrix confusion, result.csv are almost empty with nan text as well.

Thank you for your helps...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with YOLOv5 and was able to resolve it by paying attention to the `--img` (image size) and `--conf` attributes.

When calling the training script, you can define the image dimensions

```
python train.py --img 672 1216 ...
```

But you might have forgotten to use the same argument in the inference script

```
python detect.py --img 672 ...
```

Another issue is when your dataset is too small and the Recall/Precision/mAP is too low, you need to decrease the confidence filter for output during inference:

```
python detect.py ... --conf 0.7
```

You might need to reduce the `--conf`to 0.1 to see any output. Then play with it until you are satisfied with precision/recall in your output.

Comment: Thanks for your helps. I would use --img parameter but not conf. I actually solved the problem on github, it was about cuda. You can also check [here](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/4839)

Answer (score 0):

How large is your dataset? I trained yolov5s with only around 30 images with 30 to 40 labels of numbers "0" to "9" per image, it worked poorly, but when I collected more images(66 images), the network reached mAP@0.5 to around 0.99.

Comment: Thanks for your helps. I would use --img parameter but not conf. I actually solved the problem on github, it was about cuda. You can also check [here](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/4839)